# Runtime error 4160 when trying to activate a document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am writing a macro to copy text from one document to another.
The following VBA code creates a file named "temp.com"
The InFileName contains a valid path and filename.
When the code tries to activate the source document using Documents(InFileName).Activate I get a runtime error 4160. Please advise what I am doing wrong.

```
Dim InFileName As String
Documents.Add DocumentType:=wdNewBlankDocument
ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:="temp.doc", Fileformat:=wdFormatDocument
InFileName = InputBox("Enter the Book source file name.", "Book Source File")
Documents(InFileName).Activate
```

The name I entered for InFileName is "E:\Documents\My Stuff\Books\Scanned Books\Sue Grafton\A is for Alibi\Book\Source File.docx"
The string was entered as you see it minus the quote marks.

I was expecting the document specified in InFileName to be activated.

Comment: `Documents("Source File.docx").Activate` would work (assuming the file is already open) but providing the full path does not.   You should ideally provide a full path when calling `SaveAs` on the added document.

Answer (score 1):

As ***Tim's*** comment mentioned, you should reference an opened document with `Documents("Source File.docx")`.

I guess there are some scenarios where you may want to specify its full path:

- If there are more than one opened document with the same name. For example, Word `can` have both "C:\myDoc.docx" and "D:\myDoc.docx" open at the same time. Excel, for instance, `cannot` open multiple workbooks with the same name.
- If there are multiple copies of the same document on disk, it is important to know that `Documents("myDoc.docx")` is referencing the correct one. The full path helps ensure you are targeting the right document.

Please try.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub GetDocObject()
    Dim oDoc As Document, InFileName As String
    InFileName = InputBox("Enter the Book source file name.", "Book Source File")
    If Len(InFileName) > 0 Then
        For Each oDoc In Documents
            If StrComp(oDoc.FullName, InFileName, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
'                MsgBox "Found the doc."
                oDoc.Activate
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next
        MsgBox "Can't find the doc."
    End If
End Sub
```

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [StrComp function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/strcomp-function?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vblr6.chm1009035)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)